# PHP echo out each record and get total

Tags: php, sql, for-loop, foreach

I got this PHP code here...

```
$totalBalance = 0;
    foreach($resultArray as $row) {
        foreach($row as $key =>$field) {
            echo $field['remaining'] . "<br>";
        }
    }
```

$resultArray is what is returned from my SQL query into an array.

The first few records of the balance colunm are..

389.96
6433.66
52.52
107.25

however when I run this php code I get

1
5
1
3

why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

Here is the SQL query if it helps

```
SELECT c.clientid, c.clientname, c.billingdate, 
case when (select ifnull(sum(total), 0) from invoice i
where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0) - (select ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) from payment p inner join invoice i on p.invoice = i.invoiceid
where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0) < 0 then (select ii.total from invoice ii where ii.client = c.clientid and ii.isdeleted=0 order by ii.invoiceid desc limit 1)  else (select ifnull(sum(total), 0) from invoice i
where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0) - (select ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) from payment p inner join invoice i on p.invoice = i.invoiceid
where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0) end as remaining,
case c.isactive+0
        when '1' then 'Stop'
        else 'Start' 
        end as Active
FROM client c 
ORDER BY clientname
```

I did a print_r of $resultArray and got this...

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [clientid] => 1 [clientname] => client A [billingdate] => 14 [remaining] => 389.96 [active] => Stop ) [1] => Array ( [clientid] => 178 [clientname] => client B [billingdate] => 23 [remaining] => 6433.66 [active] => Stop ) [2] => Array ( [clientid] => 3 [clientname] => client C [billingdate] => 19 [remaining] => 52.52 [active] => Stop ) [3] => Array ( [clientid] => 105 [clientname] => client D [billingdate] => 23 [remaining] => 107.25 [active] => Start )
```

Comment: Can we see more, maybe your query, how you are executing it, what type of database you are using?

Comment: Can you show the output of `print_r($resultArray);`?

Comment: can you post print_r($resultArray) and post the result?

Comment: Can you also add a `var_dump($resultArray)`, too?

Comment: Shouldn't that be something like `if($key == "balance") {echo $field;}`?

Comment: Try removing the second foreach loop, then echo only $row['balance']

Comment: You don't seem to be selecting anything called `balance` in your query, and it's not present in your `$resultArray`, either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing 1 foreach to many:

```
$totalBalance = 0;

foreach($resultArray as $row) {
  echo $row['remaining'] . "<br>";        
}
```

And if you want to calculate the totalbalance:

```
$totalBalance = 0;

foreach($resultArray as $row) {
  echo $row['remaining'] . "<br>";        
  $totalBalance += $row['remaining'] ; 
}

echo $totalBalance . "<br>";
```

Comment: There is no balance field. Why bother giving a answer based on halve the info!

Comment: even when I changed to remaining i got the same result...however I changed my foreach loop to what you have and that worked

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$results = array( array('balance'=>123.45), array('balance'=>32.12));

$total = 0;

foreach( $results as $row )
{
    $total+=$row['balance'];
}

echo $total;
?>
```

Output:

> 155.57

Answer (score 0):

from print_r shouldn't it be:

```
$totalBalance = 0;
    foreach($resultArray as $row) {
        foreach($row as $key =>$field) {
            echo $field['remaining'] . "<br>";
        }
    }
```

instead of :

```
$totalBalance = 0;
    foreach($resultArray as $row) {
        foreach($row as $key =>$field) {
            echo $field['balance'] . "<br>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I replaced the balance to remaining...I am still getting the same results :(